# Creating a Huffman Codebook Given Symbol Frequencies (Python)

Tags: encoding, compression, huffman-code

Disclaimer to begin with: I am a complete beginner at Python, and all of this is really new to me.

I have been researching Huffman encoding, and I now understand how it works, but I can't seem to work out how to implement it. In my case, I am given a dict with each symbol and how often it appears in a text file. I then need to assign a binary code to each symbol.

I have tried to pop off the least-occurring symbol and adding it to a new dict, then I would assign each symbol in this new dict to be the binary representation of its location in the dict. (i.e. {'@':0000, '%':0001, etc.}) However, I don't think this is the right way to implement Huffman encoding.

Can someone possibly point me in the right direction here?